# Need to send list of objects and other object to controller using ajax post

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax

Need to send list of object and other object to controller using ajax post method. When i try to send using ajax post method using view model then list always null. Below is the code.
JavaScript Code:

```
function SubmitForm() {        
    var ServiceDefinition = $("#frmService").serialize();
    var clinicServiceList = [];
    $(".chkUserLocation:checked").each(function () {                   
        var checkBoxId = $(this).prop("id");
        checkBoxId = "#accordion" + checkBoxId;
        var emergencyPrice = $(checkBoxId).find(".clsEmergencyPrice").val();
        var opdPrice = $(checkBoxId).find(".clsOpdPrice").val();
        var ipdPrice = $(checkBoxId).find(".clsIPDPrice").val();
        var statPrice = $(checkBoxId).find(".clsStatPrice").val();
        var clinicServiceId = $(checkBoxId).find(".hdnClinicServiceId").val();
        clinicServiceList.push({
            'OpdPrice': opdPrice,
            'IpdPrice': ipdPrice,
            'ERPrice': emergencyPrice,
            'StatPrice': statPrice,
            'LocationId': $(this).prop("id"),
            'ClinicServiceId': clinicServiceId
        });            
    });
    var data1 = { 'clinicServices': clinicServiceList };
    var data = JSON.stringify(data1);
    var serviceDefination = { 'ServiceDefinition': ServiceDefinition };
    var serviceViewModel = {
        'ServiceDefinition': ServiceDefinition,
        'clinicServices': JSON.stringify(clinicServiceList)
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("ServiceForm", "Service")',
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: serviceViewModel,
        async: true,
        success: function (msg) {
          
        },
        error: function (result) {
          
        }
    });  
}
```

Controller Code:

```
public ActionResult ServiceForm(ClinicServiceViewModel serviceViewModel)
{
    return json(result);
}
```

Model Code:

```
    public class ClinicServiceViewModel 
{
    public ClinicServiceViewModel()
    {
        ServiceDefinition = new ServiceDefinition();
        ClinicServices = new List<ClinicService>();
    }
    public ServiceDefinition ServiceDefinition { get; set; }
    public List<ClinicService> ClinicServices { get; set; }

}
```

Any one guide where i am making mistake?

Comment: what is the value of `serviceViewModel` ?

Comment: serviceviewmodel is ClinicServiceViewModel.

Comment: I mean data value? the json value?

Comment: in controller it will return success or failure. Doesn't matter. When we are sending to controller then one is list of class and other is simple class.

Comment: That is type of data. But what is the value of data? Pests suppose you are sending integer, but what is the value of of that integer? Like 1 or 2 or 3

Comment: I am sending list of object data. Like in clinicserviceList i am sending decimal and integers values and in service definition i am sending string and integer values.

Answer (score 0):

please try:

var serviceViewModel = {
'ServiceDefinition': ServiceDefinition,
'clinicServices': clinicServiceList
}

data: JSON.stringify(serviceViewModel),